# Saving parameters in a file

Tags: java, reflection

I want to use a .properties file to store some parameters with values. I also want to use these parameters as class attributes in my code. How to avoid a situation where I need to define the attributes and use their names as string keys for the .properties file. I have these names twice in my code: once as an attribute and once as a string.

Reflection would help, but there is no reflection for attribute names.

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no reflection for attribute names"?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you would like to find the name of all member variables declared in i a class?

Comment: "What do you mean by "there is no reflection for attribute names"?"



I can't get the name of a class attribute as a String, can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is no reflection for attribute names

If by "attributes" you mean "fields", then this is untrue: [`Class.getDeclaredFields()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29) returns those. If you mean something else, please explain what you mean.